# REST server in Delphi XE2 pro

Tags: delphi, rest, delphi-xe2

I had a (very simple) self made REST server embeded in my application in Delphi 7 (with ICS + some stuf), it works but is not easy to maintain & extend.
Now I use Delphi XE2 Pro (without DataSnap) and I would change for a more standard solution, but yet simple.

Is there a nice easy of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Habari Web Components](http://www.habarisoft.com/habari_webcomponents.html) framework is a simple (commercial) HTTP server framework for Delphi 2009 and newer. With the [TdjRestfulComponent](http://mikejustin.wordpress.com/dwf/) it also includes a REST extension. (I am the developer of these libraries)

**TdjRestfulComponent** configuration can be done in an attribute/annotation-like style or in a more traditional procedural style way.

All HTTP methods and content-types can be mapped to different anonymous methods, and still share the same resource URI (one URI, different resource representations - depending on the requested content type). For example, to represent the resource `/myresource` in HTML, XML or JSON, it can be configured like this:

```
// respond to HTML browser GET request
&Path('myresource');
&Produces('text/html');
GET(procedure(Request: TRequest; Response: TResponse)
 begin
   Response.ContentText := '<html>Hello world!</html>';
 end);

// respond to XML client
&Path('myresource');
&Produces('application/xml');
GET(procedure(Request: TRequest; Response: TResponse)
  begin
    Response.ContentText := '<xml>Hello world!</xml>';
  end);

// respond to JSON client
&Path('myresource');
&Produces('application/json');
GET(procedure(Request: TRequest; Response: TResponse)
  begin
    Response.ContentText := '{"msg":"Hello world!"}';
  end);
```

The component also supports path parameters:

```
&Path('orders/{orderId}/lines/{lineNo');
```

will parse a URL like

```
http://mydomain.local:8080/context/orders/65432/lines/1
```

into additional query parameters (`orderId=65431` and `lineNo=1`)

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it is as simple as required, but you may take a look at our [mORMot framework](http://mormot.net).

This is a whole RESTful server, with a Client-Server ORM, and an interface-based services (like WCF). It is light and fast, but also has a lot of features.

You can do whatever kind of applications you want. For instance, some users do not use its ORM, nor its SOA, but just use it as a very fast RESTful server.

It works with any version of Delphi, from Delphi 6 up to XE2, and does NOT require a particular license: it would work also with the Starter edition. Even the database connections are included.

It is not a "standard" by itself, but it uses well-known standards, like REST, HTTP, JSON. It has per-URI build-in authentication, and a whole per-interface / per-method security policy. More than 800 pages of documentation, and a full set of regression tests included. For a quick start, [take a look at the samples](http://synopse.info/fossil/dir?name=SQLite3/Samples) - I suspect you may find it easy.

And it is free like a beer, and like a bird.

Comment: Arnaud : Yes I look your projects since a lot of time, I would found a simplier solution but mORMot is a good candidate...

Comment: @philnext Why do you think mORMot is not simple? It features a lot of things, based on a RESTful server.  But its use is plain KISS: take a look at the samples. It is used by some users only for this, without the ORM or SOA part. But I think the interface based SOA, and JSON built-in serialization, is a need for you. When your RESTful appliation will grow up, you won't have to reinvent the wheel! There is [much more than a communication layer needed](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/04/25/The-mORMot-attitude), when you want to build a RESTful server for a true application.

Comment: As I know the quality of your projects, I think that, yes, mORMot is simple and clean ORM. But now I just want a REST solution. May be mORMot is the best candidate for it, and be sure that I'll test it...